# Windows 10 lock screen background different on startup

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, windows-10-v1709

Ever since updating to 1709 (also known as the Fall Creators Update), Windows doesn't show my selected lock screen background when I start up my computer. It shows the default image. But when I go to look at the setting, the image I want is still selected.

The background I select displays properly when I lock the computer, just not when I restart. How do I fix this?

Note that the setting itself it still correct after restarting, and pressing Win+L to show the lock screen shows the correct background.

Comment: No, I don't. I knew how to fix it in 1703 and prior but that fix doesn't work anymore. My original comment intended to be a warning to the answering person: What worked before may (or may not) work now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This solution works for Windows 10 Enterprise.**

Go to the following Registry entry (or add it):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization
```

Add a new String key with the name `LockScreenImage` and the value of the complete file path of the image.

Alternatively, you can edit the group policy:

```
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization > Force a specific default lock screen image
```

[image: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization > Force a specific default lock screen image]

I found this solution [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20f8fdf0-cfb4-45bc-bb35-3c002efe60b1/registry-key-to-change-default-lock-screen-background-image-in-windows-10).

*I'm not sure if this works on non-Enterprise installations, or if non-Enterprise installations even have this issue in the first place. Let me know if this doesn't work for you.*

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with this, I had that issue before.
it is not about settings.
There is a folder about this

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData
it is a system folder, first you need to accsess, change the owner and open with admin rights

there are 2 folders in it

S-1-5-18
S-1-5-21-1819520571-1186344035-200566658-1001 <--- this folder will fix your issue

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\S-1-5-21-1819520571-1186344035-200566658-1001\ReadOnly\

there is folders named as LockScreen_B, LockScreen_* etc..

now all you have to do
find your own lock screen image folder and
windows default (your cave lock screen) folder

Different Lock Screen Picture When Turning On The Computer-sc.png

for me it was LockScreen_B and LockScreen_W
i erased the files in LockScreen_W, and copied files from LockScreen_B to LockScreen_W folder
after that reboot, win+L, etc... all the time i see my lockscreen picture

if you
i hope you can fix your issue with this, it is really annoying to see pictures that you dont want.